# Which haskell library will let me save a 2D array/vector to a png/jpg/gif... file?

Tags: arrays, haskell, image-processing, multicore

I am playing around with haskell, starting with simple plotting programs to wet my feet. I need a library that will let me save a 2D array/vector to an image file. I don't want to write a list of colors. I want to use containers that are meant for array/vector like computations and can be (well, *almost*) automagically parallelized.

**EDIT** Ability to store color images is a must.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6006304/what-haskell-representation-is-recommended-for-2d-unboxed-pixel-arrays-with-mill/6007139

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'd start with [PGM](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/pgm) library. This is a very simple uncompressed graymap format. Almost no additinal dependencies. You can convert PGM to other formats with ImageMagick or other tools.

PGM supports generic `IArray` interface, and should work with most of the standard Haskell arrays. You can easily parallelize array computations with [`Control.Parallel.Strategies`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/parallel/latest/doc/html/Control-Parallel-Strategies.html).

PGM usage example:

```
ghci> :m + Data.Array Graphics.Pgm 
ghci> let a = accumArray (+) 0 ((0::Int,0::Int),(127,127)) [ ((i,i), 1.0::Double) | i <- [0..127] ]
ghci> arrayToFile "t.pgm" (fmap round a)
```

And this is the image:

[image: t.pgm]

Otherwise you may use [Codec-Image-DevIL](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/Codec-Image-DevIL) which can save unboxed arrays to many of the image formats. You'll need [DevIL](http://openil.sourceforge.net/) library too. And you'll need to convert all arrays to that particular type of them (`UArray (Int, Int, Int) Word8`).

Finally, if you want bleeding edge, you may consider `repa` parallel arrays and corresponding `repa-io` library, which can write them [to BMP images](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/repa-io/1.1.0.0/doc/html/Data-Array-Repa-IO-BMP.html). Unfortunately, today `repa` is not yet buildable with the new GHC 7.0.2 and doesn't give performance advantages on old GHC 6.12.

Comment: Thanks for this. I need color images, so I'd look towards the devil functions.

Comment: @rpg [Codec.Image.PPM](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/ppm/latest/doc/html/Codec-Image-PPM.html) supports color.  But one of the great things about the NetPBM formats is that you don't need a library to write them; they're simple enough to just open-code anywhere.

Answer (score 6):

A new combination is:

- [repa](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/repa); for *n*-dimensional arrays, plus
- [repa-devil](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/repa-devil), for image loading in dozens of formats.

Repa is the only widely used array library that is automatically parallelized.

An example, from the [repa tutorial](http://haskell.org/haskellwiki/Numeric_Haskell%3a_A_Repa_Tutorial#Example:_Rotating_an_image_with_backpermute), using `readImage` and `writeImage`, to read an image, rotate it, and write it back out, in whatever format:

```
import System.Environment
import Data.Word
import Data.Array.Repa hiding ((++))
import Data.Array.Repa.IO.DevIL

main = do
    [f] <- getArgs
    runIL $ do
        v   <- readImage f
        writeImage ("flip-"++f) (rot180 v)

rot180 :: Array DIM3 Word8 -> Array DIM3 Word8
rot180 g = backpermute e flop g
    where
        e@(Z :. x :. y :. _)   = extent g

        flop (Z :. i         :. j         :. k) =
             (Z :. x - i - 1 :. y - j - 1 :. k)
```

Comment: repa's interoperability with the rest of ecosystem is nice. Now just add SIMD and it will be the greatest thing since sliced bread.

Answer (score 2):

The more recent [JuicyPixels](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/JuicyPixels) library let you save image to Jpg/Png/Tiff easily, you can use it in combination with [Repa](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/rep) with the [JuicyPixels-repa](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/JuicyPixels-repa) library.

Answer (score 1):

You might also want to check out [Diagrams](http://byorgey.wordpress.com/2009/01/31/diagrams-02-release/)

Example code for the dragon fractal:

```
{- Heighway dragon.  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dragon_curve. -}
module Main where

import Graphics.Rendering.Diagrams
import Control.Monad.State
import Data.Maybe

dragonStr :: Int -> String
dragonStr 0 = "FX"
dragonStr n = concatMap rules $ dragonStr (n-1)
  where rules 'X' = "X+YF+"
        rules 'Y' = "-FX-Y"
        rules c = [c]

strToPath :: String -> Path
strToPath s = pathFromVectors . catMaybes $ evalState c (0,-1)
  where c        = mapM exec s
        exec 'F' = Just `fmap` get
        exec '-' = modify left >> return Nothing
        exec '+' = modify right >> return Nothing
        exec _   = return Nothing
        left (x,y)  = (-y,x)
        right (x,y) = (y,-x)

dragon :: Int -> Diagram
dragon = lc red . curved 0.8 . strToPath . dragonStr

main = renderAs PNG "dragon.png" (Width 300) (dragon 12)
```