# Longest non decrease subseq in Haskell is slow. How to improve?

Tags: haskell, indexing, complexity-theory, sequence

```
longest'inc'subseq seq = maximum dp
    where dp = 1 : [val n | n <- [1..length seq - 1]]
          val n = (1 +) . filter'and'get'max ((<= top) . (seq!!)) $ [0..pred n]
            where top = seq!!n
          -----
          filter'and'get'max f []     = 0
          filter'and'get'max f [x]    = if f x then dp!!x else 0
          filter'and'get'max f (x:xs) = if f x then ( if vx > vxs then vx else vxs ) else vxs
            where vx  = dp!!x
                  vxs = filter'and'get'max f xs
```

that take about 1-2s with lenght of seq = 1000
while in python is come out imtermedialy

in python

```
def longest(s):
    dp = [0]*len(s)
    dp[0] = 1
    for i in range(1,len(s)):
        need = 0
        for j in range (0, i):
            if s[j] <= s[i] and dp[j] > need:
                need = dp[j]
        dp[i] = need + 1
    return max(dp)
```

and when  length of seq is 10000, the haskell program run sooo long
while python return the answer after 10-15s

Can we improve haskell speed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your core problem is that you're using the wrong data structure in Haskell for this algorithm. You've translated an algorithm that depends on *O(1)* lookups on a sequence (as in your Python code), into one that does *O(n)* lookups on a list in Haskell.

Use like-for-like data structures, and then your complexity problems will take care of themselves. In this case, it means using something like `Data.Vector.Unboxed` to represent the sequence, which has *O(1)* indexing, as well as low constant overheads in general.

Comment: Is Data.Vector.Unboxed more efficient than arrays such as DiffUArray for example ? If so, could you please explain why ?

Comment: DiffArray is particularly slow, as it is relatively naive. It was removed from the core library set a few years ago. For comparisons of array libraries, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6006304/what-haskell-representation-is-recommended-for-2d-unboxed-pixel-arrays-with-mill/6007139#6007139

Answer (score 3):

With nothing more than a really mindless wrapping of your lists into Vectors I get 2.5 seconds when the input list is `[1..10000]`.

```
import qualified Data.Vector as V
import Data.Vector (Vector, (!))

main = print $ liss [0..10000]

liss :: [Int] -> Int
liss seqL = V.maximum dp
    where dp = V.fromList $ 1 : [val n | n <- [1..length seqL - 1]]
          seq = V.fromList seqL
          val n = (1 +) . filter'and'get'max ((<= top) . (seq!)) $ [0..pred n]
            where top = seq!n
          -----
          filter'and'get'max :: (Int -> Bool) -> [Int] -> Int
          filter'and'get'max f []     = 0
          filter'and'get'max f [x]    = if f x then dp!x else 0
          filter'and'get'max f (x:xs) = if f x then ( if vx > vxs then vx else vxs ) else vxs
            where vx  = dp!x
                  vxs = filter'and'get'max f xs
```

The compilation and execution:

```
tommd@Mavlo:Test$ ghc --version
The Glorious Glasgow Haskell Compilation System, version 7.0.3
tommd@Mavlo:Test$ ghc -O2 so.hs
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( so.hs, so.o )
Linking so ...
tommd@Mavlo:Test$ time ./so
10001

real    0m2.536s
user    0m2.528s
```

A worker-wrapper transformation on `filter'and'get'max` seems to shave off another second.

Also, I don't understand why you need that middle case (`filter'and'get'max f [x]`), shouldn't it work fine without that? I guess this changes the result if `dp!x < 0`. Note eliminating that saves 0.3 seconds right there.

And the python code you provided takes ~ 10.7 seconds (added a call of `longest(range(1,10000));`).

```
tommd@Mavlo:Test$ time python so.py

real    0m10.745s
user    0m10.729s
```

Comment: thanks you. sorry because of my english. but i don't understand what you said about fillter'and'get'max f [x]. i think this is a pattern for a function that take a list as argument. and dp!x cannot < 0 because it is a count varialbe