# Why is there no mapM for repa arrays?

Tags: haskell, frp, repa

#### Background

I am using `repa` more as a "management" tool. I pass around `reactive-banana`s `AddHandlers` in an `Array`: `Array D DIM2 (AddHandler Bool)`.

Currently I am using this kludge:

```
mapMArray :: (Monad m, R.Source r a, R.Shape sh)  => (a -> m b) -> Array r sh a -> m (Array D sh b)
mapMArray f a = do
    l <- mapM f . R.toList $ a
    return $ R.fromFunction sh (\i -> l !! R.toIndex sh i)
  where sh = R.extent a
```

So I can do something like this:

```
makeNetworkDesc :: Frameworks t => Array D DIM2 (AddHandler Bool) -> Moment t ()
makeNetworkDesc events = do

    -- inputs
    aes <- mapMArray fromAddHandler events

    -- outputs
    _ <- mapMArray (reactimate . (print <$>)) aes
```

#### Question

Is there a reason why this is not included in `repa`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Basically for the same reason there's nothing like [`parMapM` in parallel](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/parallel-2.2.0.1): `mapM` and `mapM_` (or monadic actions in general) *destroy* parallelism. Here's a simple example:

```
next :: State Int Int
next = modify (+1) >> get
```

Now, a hypothetical `repaMapM` needs to sequence all steps in the `State` monad, if one would use `repaMapM (const next)`. Since this clearly defies parallelism (and can also lead to low performance), it isn't part of repa. After all, high performance and parallelism is right there in repa's description (emphasis mine):

> Repa provides **high performance**, regular, multi-dimensional, shape polymorphic **parallel** arrays.

Comment: Hmm ... so as long as I don't need the parallelism, I should be fine. Otoh I seem to misuse repa. A cursory search on hackage provided no other matrix libraries that have stencil operations. Is there an alternative to repa in that regard?

Comment: If the [three year old answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6006304/what-haskell-representation-is-recommended-for-2d-unboxed-pixel-arrays-with-mil) still hold, then no. There's `accelerate`, but that's a whole other beast. All in all it depends on what you want to do. The code you provided in your answer can be easily accomplished with `Data.Vector(*)`, but in this case you need to write stencils yourself (also `Data.Vector` doesn't support multi-dimensional indices, but that's something you can easily fix with a wrapper and additional functions).

Comment: Yeah ... I was hoping to get around that ;)

Comment: Couple years later and we now do have a library called [`massiv`](https://github.com/lehins/massiv) that has all of the desired features. It has sequential `mapM` for any Monad, it has `mapIO` that can be parallelized and it has much better implementation of stencils that work for arbitrary dimension. Overall it is more performant than `Repa`, easier to use than `accelerate` (and just as fast with llvm backend)